# Getting 403 Forbidden when trying to call /users/{userid}/presence

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to call [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userid}/presence](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7Buserid%7D/presence) from within an application. The application is registered in Azure and has been granted the **Presence.ReadWrite.All** permission. When I generate a token using the application's ID and secret, and decode on jwt.ms, the token contains the following roles:

```
"roles": [
    "Presence.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWrite.All",
    "AuditLog.Read.All",
    "DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All"
  ]
```

Other Graph API calls that require privileges (/users/{userid}/managedDevices) for instance, complete without issue. I do note that the current documentation, even for the Beta API, says that the required permissions are Presence.**Read**.All, which cannot be assigned to an application only delegated, but one would logically assume that Presence.**ReadWrite**.All, which can be assigned to an application, would be able to read presence as well.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Get presence documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), **GET /users/{id}/presence** does not support application permissions. The permission Presence.ReadWrite.All is only supported for Set Presence. Check more on [this GitHub Thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/13457)

You can file a feature request in the [M365 Developer Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).